# Confusion with Spring Security-based authentication with mongo backed db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm trying to login a user to a webpage, where credentials are stored in mongodb.
I'm using spring boot and wasn't aware of spring security features.

That's why I ended up, using the following controller code, which works:

```
@RequestMapping("/auth")
String auth(@ModelAttribute("credential") Credential credential) throws AuthenticationFailedException {
    handler.authenticateUser(credential);
    log.debug("user: " + credential.getUsername() + " authenticated successfully via /auth");
    return "main";
}
```

handler:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

public boolean authenticateUser(Credential credential) throws AuthenticationFailedException {        
    User authenticatedUser = repository.findByCredentialUsername(credential.getUsername());

    if (authenticatedUser == null)
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException(
                "cant find any user with name: " + credential.getUsername());

    boolean matches = EncryptionUtils.matchEncryptedPassword(credential.getPassword(),
            authenticatedUser);

    if (!matches)
        throw new AuthenticationFailedException(
                "provided password is not matching password stored in database");

    return matches;
}
```

After realizing that that servlet filters etc. are relatively easy to setup with spring-security, I had changed my code, so I ended up with this:

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  UserAuthenticationService userAuthService;

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setUserDetailsService(userAuthService);
    provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    return provider;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.userDetailsService(userAuthService).authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/login")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
            formLogin().loginPage("/").and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().csrf().disable();

  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
  }
```

SecurityWebInit:

```
public class SecurityWebInit extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
  public SecurityWebInit() {
    super(SecurityConfig.class);
  }
}
```

UserAuthenticationService:

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserAuthenticationService.class);
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository repository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repository.findByCredentialUsername(username);
        log.debug("called user auth service..");
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("username :"+username+" not found.");
        else {
            AuthenticatedUser authUser = new AuthenticatedUser(user);
            return authUser;
        }
  }
}
```

AuthenticatedUser - model:

```
public class AuthenticatedUser implements UserDetails {  
  private User user; // user is my own model, not of spring-framework
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticatedUser.class);

  public AuthenticatedUser(User user) {
      this.user = user;
  }
  .. //rest of interface impl. (any method returns true)

  //no roles or authorities modeled, yet
  @Override 
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
      return null;
  }
```

Modified controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/login")
String auth2(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) throws AuthenticationFailedException {
    Credential cred = new Credential();
    cred.setUsername(username);
    cred.setPassword(password);        
    handler.authenticateUser(cred);
    log.debug("user: " + cred.getUsername() + " authenticated successfully via /login");
    return "main";
}
```

Template:

```
<form method="post" action="/login" th:object="${credential}">
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control"
      id="username" placeholder="Username/Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"
      class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default login-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

All of the provided code, is more less clustered together from another tutorials and examples. 
When I authenticate via form-based login, it actually works. But after I have been logged in, when I navigate to `localhost:8080/<anyRestrictedUrl>` it still redirects me to login form.
I also placed some `log.debug(..)` inside of `UserAuthenticationService`, but I can't see any of them at all.. 
In most other examples, I can't even see the basic controller method mapped to `\login`, but I think this is because of spring doing this 4 me behind the scenes?!

Please note, that I not using any authorities and / or roles, as that isn't modeled in db, yet. Is this a must have, when using spring security, as most of the examples include roles and authorities.

**Edit:** (Relevant parts of pom.xml):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

**Update:** (Things I've tried on above mentioned code):

1) Setting other session policy: (not working)

```
http.userDetailsService(userAuthService).authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/register", "/", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/login")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
    formLogin().loginPage("/").and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS).and().csrf().disable();
```

2) Replacing @Override with @Autowired annotation (got that from another SO post - not working):

```
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

Comment: And where did you specify your restricted URL's?

Comment: isnt that done in `configure(HttpSecurity http)`: `...anyRequest().authenticated()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could resolve this..
With reading of [this blog post](http://www.baselogic.com/blog/http-status-405-spring-security-custom-form-login-javaconfig/) it turned out, that its needed! to specify the `usernameParameter(..), passwordParameter(..)` in `config(HttpSecurity http)`, unlike they do in many basic examples or tutorials. So relying on default values was my pity. I had to append:

```
formLogin().loginPage("/")
       .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
       .failureUrl("/")
       .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
       .usernameParameter("username") //needed, if custom login page
       .passwordParameter("password") //needed, if custom login page
```

Without those param-settings the `UserDetailsService` implementation gets not triggered.

Hope it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SessionCreationPolicy` to `IF_REQUIRED` or `ALWAYS`. Currently, it's "stateless" which means that your session will never be created or obtained for `SecurityContext`.

Comment: I tried that, but it is still not working. Also tried removing the `sessionManagement()` completely from config, but same result